# Perl 5.8 Get Stdout from SSH command

Tags: perl, ssh, centos, ipc, qx

I need to create a script that will work on `CentOS 5.x` and `CentOS 6.x` boxes. CentOS 5.x uses `Perl 5.8` and CentOS 6.x uses `Perl 5.10`. The goal is to be able to ssh into a box, that has a key exchange in place, then run `python -V`, to determine if the default version is `python 2.6`.

I'm guessing if I get a script that works with Perl 5.8, that it'll work for 5.10 as well. I made some progress with `Net::SSH:Any` to have to throw it away, as it looks like it works with Perl 5.12 and newer.

I've tried `IPC::System::Simple` and `qx` as well, but haven't had luck capturing the output.

Some of my failed attempts:

Fail 1:

```
use IPC::System::Simple qw(system systemx capture capturex);
my $output = capture("/usr/bin/ssh root\@10.100.10.56 python -V");
print "out: " . $output . "\n";
```

Fail 2:

```
my $output = qx(ssh root\@10.100.10.56 python -V);
print "out: " . $output . "\n";
```

Fail 3:

```
my @output = qx(ssh root\@10.100.10.56 python -V);
print "@output\n";
```

I'm not sure if the call of ssh is playing with anything and am in desperate need of a sanity check. When the command is run, the output is shown on the screen, but not stored in the variable, which I can do substring checks against. The `$output` variable is left blank. If I'm missing something, please let me know. Thanks :)

Comment: `python -V` may write to `STDERR` instead of `STDOUT`. Also, why not just use a different module for SSH like `Net::OpenSSH`?

Comment: I looked into `SSH`, `SSH2`, and `OpenSSH`. I've tried to simplify things and just run the command directly to get things working. Is there a way to get `qx` to capture stderr too?

Comment: There is. See [How to capture both STDOUT and STDERR in two different variables using Backticks in Perl](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8384619/176646). However, you should really avoid using bacticks/`system` when there is a pure Perl equivalent. `Net::OpenSSH` has this nice [`system`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::OpenSSH#ssh-system-opts-cmd) method that lets you control `STDIN`, `STDOUT`, `STDERR`, and more.

Comment: Looks like you found the same link as me a couple minutes later :) I looked at Net::OpenSSH on cpan and when I went to the very bottom it looks like it is support with 5.10 and later, so wouldn't work for my CentOS 5.x boxes. I'd prefer to use the newer stuff anyway, but I need to support existing customers :)

Comment: I don't know what you're talking about. `Net::OpenSSH` passes all tests on [CPAN Testers](http://www.cpantesters.org/distro/N/Net-OpenSSH.html?oncpan=1&distmat=1&version=0.62) for 5.8.x. I think you're just looking at the license terms, which have nothing to do with whether a module will run on earlier Perl versions.

Comment: IIRC, Net::SSH::Any only requires perl 5.8.

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out from ThisSuitIsBlackNot's advice. I found [Getting STDOUT, STDERR, and response code from external *nix command in perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8733131/getting-stdout-stderr-and-response-code-from-external-nix-command-in-perl) which showed me how to update my code to get stderr too, which is as follows:

```
my $output = qx(ssh root\@10.100.10.56 python -V 2>&1);
print "out: " . $output . "\n";
```

This gave me what I needed. Thx!

Comment: I'm glad I don't have that layer of complexity to have to fight with too :) Might work with cygwin, but would be a side project :)

Comment: My point is, Python is cross-platform, so there's no reason your command to check the version should be restricted to a single OS. If you use a module like `Net::OpenSSH` instead of backticks, you don't have to worry about OS-specific quoting and I/O redirection. `my @cmd = qw(python -V); $ssh->system({ stderr_to_stdout => 1 }, @cmd) or die $ssh->error;`

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot: Net::OpenSSH does not work on Windows, not even under Cygwin Perl. That's the main reason that pushed me to create Net::SSH::Any.

Comment: @salva You mean it doesn't *run* on Windows, correct? I'm just talking about connecting to a remote Windows machine. Of course, I've never tried it so I could just be talking out my you-know-what.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot, yes, Net::OpenSSH can connect to Windows machines. Version 0.62 also got support for quoting commands for Win32 and `cmd.exe`.

Comment: @salva Good to know. BTW, the only reason I recommended `Net::OpenSSH` is that I took the OP's statement about `Net::SSH::Any` only working for 5.12+ at face value. In retrospect, I should have double checked that. That, and the statement "The API is not stable and may change between releases" in the documentation.

Comment: Net::SSH::Any provides just a subset of Net::OpenSSH features, but it does work on Windows. If you only need your scripts to work on Linux/Unix systems, Net::OpenSSH is actually a better option.